# Use logInsights based on a field and then dedup data

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have the following logs in my cloudwatch:

```
2023-12-21T13:19:32.301-08:00
(<unique Id here>) Method request body before transformations: 
{
    "executionDetails": {
        "executionId": "<a different unique Id here>",
        "userName": "<username>",
        "sourcePackage": "<path>"
    },
    "requestType": "RAW_REQUEST"
}
```

and like these as well:

```
2023-12-21T13:19:32.301-08:00
(<same unique Id>) Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{
    "executionDetails": {
        "executionId": "<same different unique id as in above logs>",
        "userName": "<username>",
        "sourcePackage": "<path>"
    },
    "requestType": "RAW_REQUEST"
}
```

How do I get all logs which have RequestType as RAW_REQUEST and also dedup them based on executionId?

The above 2 should display a count of 1 RAW_REQUEST.

What I have tried till now?

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /Endpoint request body after transformations:/
| parse @message '"requestType":"RAW_REQUEST"' as requestType
| stats count(executionId) as executionId
| display executionId, requestType
```

This does not give me the right data.

I also want to do the same for other requestTypes. And then do a math on the unique count of each of them.